# making method final, if we really wanted to enforce this

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i am still reading factory patterns on head first.  We have an pizzaStore example and trying to localize our pizzaStore class to let franchies freedom to have their own regional style.

To do this, we changed to pizzaStore class to abstract class, and moved our factory object to "abstract createPizza(String type);" method. It is ok, i understood why.

If you look at the picture, i underlined the sentence. What it means ? " **if we really want to enforce**, we could make the method final ? "

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that subclasses are supposed to implement `createPizza`, but are required by contract to **not** override `orderPizza`, just call it. This policy can be enforced by making the method final.

When you design a class for inheritance, you must generally take care of all the details involved in how exactly the class is supposed to be extended.

Comment: Thank you ,Are there any other way except final ?

Answer (score 3):

If you make a method final classes inheriting the method cannot overwrite it. This ensures that the implementation in PizzaStore is used by all the subclasses.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a method as `final`, prevents the subclasses from overidding it.

Answer (score 1):

If you make orderPizza method **final**, you cant `override` in your **subclasses**, but you can still access them. methods marked with final cant be overriden in your subclass.

Comment: Thank you ,Are there any other way except final ?

Comment: @talhakosen what do you mean any other way except final??

Comment: If you mean, what other scopes can restrict from overriding the method, private and static methods cant be overriden as well.

Answer (score 1):

Final methods cannot be overridden thus any inheriting class has the same method, they are enforced to have that same method.

Comment: Thank you ,Are there any other way except final ?

Answer (score 1):

This means that `ChicagoStylePizzaStore` is not allowed to override orderPizza().

The java final keyword: `final orderPizza()`
 enforced that the sub classes cannot overide that method.

Class Chicago then has to call orderPizza() from PizzaStorre() and not from an own method with same name.